# SSH or Console in XBian1.0Alpha3

Tags: ssh, kodi

I am running Xbian1.0Alpha3 on my RaspberryPi model B. I was wondering how to switch to linux console from graphical view, I could not find out. Does anybody know ?

Another issue is SSH, I found on RPi forum that initial credentials are : root/raspberry but this is not working in Xbian. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You **should** be able to switch tty using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Any <kbd>F</kbd> key under 6 will work and you can use the <kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>F8</kbd> key to get back to the GUI. Although it is possible that this functionality is disabled in XBMC. If that is the case you wont be able to access a console unless there is a console app in the XBMC store.

From the [XBian FAQ](http://xbian.org/faqs/what-is-the-ssh-username-and-password/):

> Q: What are the SSH credentials?
>
> A: User: **xbian** Password: **raspberry**

Comment: Doesn't work on my Xbian-1.0-Alpha4... Strange, I thought this would work on any Linux. I'll try ssh, thanks for user and pasword.

Comment: As I said, some versions of XBMC disable this functionality :(

Answer (score 0):

As is noted in [this blog post](http://blog.jc21.com/2012-09-13/xbmc-on-your-raspberry-pi/), you have to exit the xbmc application by hitting the shutdown icon and selecting "exit" (or, use the keyboard shortcut "s" then select exit.)  Doing this will bring you to tty1 where you can do maintenance tasks to the image (such as updating it.)

For me, on 1.0-Alpha5, it took almost 45 seconds for XBMC to close.  You might think it's frozen in the "exit" state, but just give it time.

As Jivings stated, per the [Xbian FAQ](http://xbian.org/faqs/what-is-the-ssh-username-and-password/), the credentials to login are below, tested and verified as of 1.0-alpha5.

> Q: What are the SSH credentials?
>
> A: User: **xbian** Password: **raspberry**

Comment: the link to the FAQ is broken :/

Comment: @tapped-out thanks for noticing that, I looked it up and corrected it.